# Need tips for logic of posting with images

Tags: java, php, laravel, amazon-s3, logic

I am currently trying to build an app wherein a user can upload a post with an image.

Currently, what I'm doing is reserving an id from the POST table on my database, meaning I create an insert request and it is empty having only an ID. Then I upload the image to AWS S3. Upon success of image upload, I update the row and put all the contents of the post including the link of the uploaded image for it to be loaded when need on my app.

The problem is this is insecure. Because if the upload process fails, an entire row is wasted on the database. Even if I delete the row, another user might have entered another row, so an ID is skipped because it is auto incremented on every insert.

I need tips on how I can optimize this process without wasting a row and id.

Comment: Don't bind the image with id of the post... How I would do it is like this: Make model Post and the post has an attribute image... and that attribute is just the string of the image name on save and then when the Post is saved to DB you have the string/name and make the link to the image in view and that's it

Comment: How is the ID generated?  In your code?  With a database type (i.e. `Serial`)?  There is no need for a two step process like you have.

Comment: @lewis4u I have an image attribute on my model. Are you saying that I save the data including the link to the image even when it is not yet completely uploaded? I have a two step process because I get an ID from the database which is reserved, then I upload the image to Amazon S3 with the ID that I received from database as its filename/key on Amazon S3.

Comment: @stdunbar I insert a new row on the server and get that ID then send it back to the user which the application uses as filename/key for the image to be uploaded. It is just a varchar on my server as it only holds the image link when the upload is complete.

Comment: No don't save any data if it is not complete... in your case if the image is not uploaded....if the image is not there it should not save. I am just saying that it is a bad practice to couple the ID with the image...don't do that. Image doesn't have to know the row ID, but the Post must know which image is uploaded.

Comment: @lewis4u Okay thank you, I get the idea. But do you have any recommendations on how I can simplify this? If only amazon s3 can generate an id/filename on its own, I would just save that link to my database. But I have to generate it myself which is why I had to go thru my server to get an ID for me to use so that I can avoid overwriting of images on Amazon S3 before I upload the image, and then update the values again  on the server when the upload is complete.

Comment: Can you open this video?? https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-3/episodes/12

Comment: @lewis4u I watched the video, but I don't think I can apply it like this. Because this is a mobile application that I'm trying this on, not exactly a web app. So if I did it like this, that would be kind of wasteful as I would be uploading it twice, first to the server, then upload it to the S3 from the server upon receiving the request. I probably haven't mentioned that my database and my file storage aren't on the same server.

Comment: I don't know how did you make your code and your environment...it sounds rather complicated...you should save the data only to S3... your server should have nothing to do with storing the data, on the server is only the code to store the data, and the location should be S3

Comment: @lewis4u I think you misunderstood what I said, or maybe I said it in the wrong way. I didn't mean that I would store/save the uploaded image on my server and then upload it to S3. I was saying that maybe it would be better to have it sent to S3 right away from the mobile app, instead of having it sent thru my EC2 server just to be sent/passed to S3 for the image to be stored. Which is why I thought that maybe getting an ID first could work since it's lighter than having to pass an image file twice.

Comment: but you are not passing the image twice....when user starts the mobile app....the mobile app should hit your Laravel API server and then that code in your controller should be something like "save image to Amazon S3" and then that image goes from mobile phone directly to the Amazon...your controller is only like pointing the right direction where to go... and it uses a little bit CPU for that, nothing else....the image is then uploaded directly to Amazon

Comment: Thank you. I finally got the idea. However. How do I handle it if the upload to s3 fail? I may have to open another question

Comment: Images should be child table. Either 1:1 or 1:n if you are saving more than one image per post. Controller method should flow like: uploading image and saving response object to variable. After check that variable is not false, you save post model with request data and after that image model with S3 returned data. No need to overthink this.

Comment: @Tpojka I actually have a separate table for the images, even if for the mean time, I only accept 1 image upload per posts, so that It would be easier to change in the future. I have come up with a solution as well that I would generate a UUID in the mobile app, and use that as the image name which I then upload to Amazon S3. Upon success of upload, I will then send the post to my EC2 server along with the link of the uploaded image.